# How to access to a component of a children GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to enable a health bar canvas, which is a child of my enemy.
I don't know how to access a component of a children.

The script is attached to a 'FightController'. I will find the enemies by their tag. The enemy-GameObject have each a 'Health bar'-GameObject.

```
void Start()
{
    enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("enemy");

    for(int enemyNumber = 0; enemyNumber < 5; enemyNumber++){
         enemy[enemyNumber].GetComponentInChildren<Canvas>().enabled = true;  //This is not working.
    }
}
```

I get following error: 'NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: Well, you could try to use `transform.GetChild[0].GetComponent<Canvas>()` and make sure it isn't null. Of course if the canvas is the nth children of your enemy then use `GetChild[n]` instead of `0`

Comment: Cool thanks! This is working. You can answer it directly, so I can give you the star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try to use `transform.GetChild[0].GetComponent<Canvas>()` and make sure it isn't null. Of course if the canvas is the `n`th child of your enemy then use `GetChild[n]` instead of `0`.

*Copied from my comment*